# adding offset to datetime values in Kusto

Tags: datetime, datetimeoffset, azure-data-explorer

How do we add time offsets to datetime value in Kusto? As an example, I have table with the time in UTC and offset values.

```
utcStartDateTime        uctOffset
2020-04-16T00:00:25Z    08:00:00
2020-04-16T00:00:47Z    10:00:00
```

I would like to add them. I tried the below with no luck.

```
datetime_add('hour',datetime_part('hour', todatetime(utcOffset)),todatetime(utcStartDateTime))
```

The below works but it is good for only hourly offsets.

```
 datetime_add('hour', toint(split(utcOffset, ":" )[0]),todatetime(utcStartDateTime))
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, datetime values would be typed as `datetime`, and timespan values would be typed as `timespan`, and then you can simply add them

the following example assumes the worst, i.e. both your columns are typed as `string` (based on how you attempted to solve it in your original question)

```
datatable(utcStartDateTime:string, uctOffset:string)
[
    '2020-04-16T00:00:25Z', '08:00:00',
    '2020-04-16T00:00:47Z', '10:00:00'
]
| extend date_with_offset = todatetime(utcStartDateTime) + totimespan(uctOffset)
```

Comment: Prefect! Thanks Yoni. How to give the new column an alias name?

Comment: Great. I am just getting started with Kusto and finding it very powerful. Thanks for helping out.